# Meta refresh full url with hash fragments

Tags: wordpress, url, page-refresh

When I am in page gallery my full url contains item number as hash and when I refresh my page using meta refresh `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">` it couldnt save the item number in the url.

For example when I am in my five item after refresh i want to keep my url with the same item number "#item=5".

any suggestion plz?

Comment: page link please..

Comment: @CBroe http://www.viepratique.fr/beaute/conseils-beaute/15-gestes-beaute-a-ne-pas-negliger-cet-ete-591395.html#item=1

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. The hash is a merely client-side construct, and does not even get send to the server. But automatically refreshing a page, especially with such a short interval, is in most cases a usability nightmare anyway. What’s that supposed to achieve here?